# Can I build CentOS on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine?

Tags: centos, compiling

Preface: I haven't built an OS since Solaris, with momentary foray into Yellow Dog Linux, both long ago.

I have a build machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (which may eventually be changed to CentOS). I need to use it to get my feet down on building CentOS' latest stable release (the whole thing, kernel and all).

Can this be done without heroics, or should I find or build a machine running an appropriate OS to do this?

The instructions I've found for CentOS seem to all assume that I'm doing the build on a machine that has CentOS or similar, I guess, with yum, etc. I've seen references to using Mock to build RPMs on any platform, but I'm not sure how this fits into the puzzle to build the whole OS.

Comment: What do you mean "build CentOS?" It's just a download; gone are the days of needing to rebuild your own kernel all the time. In fact, it's kind of discouraged (e.g. no official way to do kernel modules) You might be glad to know that "yum" from Yellow Dog is still used by CentOS. If you mean cross-compile some code to target CentOS, then you can easily spin up a Docker container with C7, install compilers, and go to town.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: Thank you for the reply. My (new) job is going to involve deep diving into kernel and user drivers as well as libraries. I can't say that the point will come where I need to modify the kernel, but I will not be surprised if I will want to look at source code. I'm very sure that I'll be crashing many times and needing to debug what's going on. So I am just figuring at the outset that I might as well figure out how to do the whole build. Thank you for your advice on Docker; I'll get familiar with it. I also have a Mac and can put CentOS in a VM and work there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, good that you're planning to build an OS from scratch albeit these days most people doesn't care unless you have a very specific and mandatory requirement.

As to the question. Building CentOS from Ubuntu is bit tricky (as I tried an failed at matching the yum db. Ubuntu version 14.04). **I would not recommend that** though I do not know how much is heroic for you. May be you can try **Singularity**

**P.S:** Please show some research effort in your questions as they might encourage those who attempt to answer your specific problems.

Good to see you from a custom built CentOS machine soon. :)

Comment: Couldn't it be done using a CentOS docker image on Ubuntu?

Comment: @MikaelKjær: Docker is good for running applications which would require only a subset of OS dependencies. Whereas building an OS requires complete set of dependency compatibility which IMHO is rather tricky. I would not recommend that

Comment: Thanks. Docker is good for a lot more than running applications. We use it to build several OS/distro specific things, but I am unaware of how much is required to build a full distro hence my question.

Comment: @MikaelKjær; As for my understanding about Docker goes, it provides necessary dependencies and environment for running your application and you can build some distro specific things as you have mentioned. As to "How much is required?", is subjective and my opinion would be "A lot"

Comment: @RussellB: Thanks for great information, and your recommendation to avoid trying it. Also thank you for the suggestion to be explicit about my research (I was trying to be terse). It sounds like running with the wind means installing CentOS and building there. Being so long away from doing this, I was naive in thinking that building this would be (essentially) like building many complex programs which builds exclusively out of its source tree. Again, thanks. I'll work at doing a better job on StackExchange as well.